# Javascript Navigation selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nav selector on my site that works well but I want to now change the navigation for 5 destinations while keeping things the same for the other 2 cities

here is my working code :

```
 <!-- Hero nav section -->
    <div class="no-gutter">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/"+cityName+"-tours"%>"
                         <%if(url.Contains(cityName + "-tours")){%>class="current"<%}%>><% if (cityName == "washington-dc") {%>Washington, D.C.<% } else {%><%= cityName.Replace('-', ' ')%><%; } %> tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/private-tours"%>"
                         <%if(url.Contains("private")){%>class="current"<%} %>>private tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/nextday-tours"%>" 
                         <%if(url.Contains("nextday")){%>class="current"<%}%>>next day tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Application["baseURL"].ToString() + Session["lang"] + "/"+country+"/"+cityName+"/sale-tours"%>" 
                         <%if(url.Contains("sale")){%>class="current"<%}%>>sale tours</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How I can keep it for Paris and London and change whats displayed for 5 italian cities..

ask for more info please !

Comment: Um, maybe I'm just missing it because of your templating, but I don't see Paris or London anywhere. Consider creating a plnkr or jsfiddle to better demonstrate your problem.

Comment: So how do you want to change their display? Different text? Different links?

Comment: For italian cities I would like to display city names on the buttons of that page - while for the other two cities paris and london i would like to keep things as they are.  so keeping things as they are for 2 cities while changing it for italian cities

Comment: can I change add a function to specific cities ? the nav was created using hero nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;
 
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

$.each( arr, function( index, value ){
    sum += value;
});
 
console.log( sum ); // 15
```

JQuery code to iterate over jQuery and non jQuery objects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).